# c++ In member initialization pass new object in constructor

Tags: c++

In initializing the member variable theOtherThing below, the OtherThing class has a constructor that takes an object of type "Line", but I'm not passing an argLine through SomeClass' constructor. I want to declare a new Line object in the constructor, but I don't know how. I guess I could initialize it in the body of the constructor, and maybe I'm trying to be too slick.

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(const Polygon& argPoly,
                     const Point&   argPoint)
                     //No argLine being passed here
   :
      thePolygon           (argPoly),
      thePoint             (argPoint),
      theOtherThing        (new OtherThing(Line())), //Something like this 
                           //But, the above does not work
                           //Nor (new OtherThing(Line aLine))
                           //Nor (new OtherThing(new Line())         
{}
```

OtherThing class has a constructor that takes an object of type "Line"

```
OtherThing::OtherThing(const Line& argLine)
   :
      theLine              (argLine)
{}
```

Line has a default constructor that initializes its data members.

```
Line::Line()
{
  //Data members get initilized here
}
```

How do I do this? Maybe I'm over complicating it.

**EDIT**

Declaration of theOtherThing:

```
Private :
   OtherThingPtr theOtherThing //It's an implementaion of C++ std::shrd_ptr
```

**EDIT**

Line Class

```
class Line
{
public:
   double this;
   double that;
   Line();
   ... some other constructors and methods 
}
```

OtherThing Class

```
class OtherThing : RefCountedObj
{
public:
   OtherThing(const Line& argLine)

private:
   Line  theLine;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ha ha. Just kidding... new OtherThing(Line()) works. Anyone care to elaborate for pedagogical reasons?

Comment: `new OtherThing(Line())` should not work as you are not working with pointers,  If `theOtherThing` is an `OtherThing` then you should only need `theOtherThing(Line{})`

Comment: Well, it compiled, can't say it actually worked though...

Comment: Please, show us `OtherThing` declaration.

Comment: Just ran and it seemed to work. @GeorgeSovetov I edited to show declaration.

Comment: @Kentheglish I meant `class OtherThing : public ... { ... theLine; .. }`. What's type of `theLine`?

Comment: @Kentheglish if your program "seemed to work", then what's the point of this question? Also, your question seems to contradict your comment stating that it doesn't in fact work. But you forgot to tell us *how* it doesn't work. In any case, create a [mcve].

Comment: @user2079303 sorry. I jumped the gun a bit.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant with `Line()` will compile. `OtherThing` constructor accepts lvalue reference, you pass rvalue (temporary object); you can use this temporary `Line` object in `OtherThing` constructor. The question is what's type of `theLine`.

If `theLine` is `const Line&` and you refer to `theLine` after object is constructed, you will invoke undefined behavior. If `theLine` is just `Line`, you call copy constructor which should be OK.

Comment: @NathanOliver I just reread [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary). I make some changes to clarify what I meant. Does it contradict with my answer?

Comment: Nathan may be referring to your first paragraph which states that the problem is the constructor taking a reference. In fact, the constructor is just fine. If `OtherThing::theLine` is indeed a reference, then *that* is the problem (or the call to the constructor), not the constructor itself.

Comment: @user2079303 Yes, I should reformulate.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the class **OtherThing** being a member like thePolygon & thePoint, and the code for **OtherThing** being the following (as above):

```
class OtherThing
{
    OtherThing(const Line& argLine) : theLine(argLine){}
    Line theLine;
};
```

You only need to do the following:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(const Polygon& argPoly,
                 const Point&   argPoint)
                 //No argLine being passed here
   :
      thePolygon           (argPoly),
      thePoint             (argPoint),
      theOtherThing        (Line()), ...
```